# forcing a log rotation in python logging module

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

If I have a rotating logging file. (logging_file.log) that rotates when x condition is met. How do I make it rotate? I know the rotating log module rotates automatically when the size exceeds a certain amount, but how do I make this rotation happen in the logging module for a different condition that is not size. Or how do I just force it to rotate the logging into a new logging file for whatever reason. Is there a function or command for this?
Simply put how do I manually rotate a logging file if I want to use a newer and archive the old one.
something like

```
if lines_in_file > 3
    rotate()
```

[note: the condition to make it rotate is irrelevant but I'm trying to ask for what function will make this rotation happen. Is there a simple function that does the job of rotate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have (or can save) a reference to the appropriate instance of `RotatingFileHandler` from when you configured the logger. You just need to invoke its `doRollover` method:

```
rfh = RotatingFileHandler('foo.log')

...

rfh.doRollover()
```

More generally, `RotatingFileHandler.doRollover` uses `BaseRotatingHandler.rotate`, which takes the source and destination file names. `rotate` either calls the handler's `rotator` attribute with the same arguments, or just moves the source to the destination.

Comment: I tried doing that but its not doing anything. (It's not rolling over or rotating)

```
handler = RotatingFileHandler(f'{file_name}', backupCount = 5)
my_logger.warning("Warning!")
C = 94949494994949449
if C > 3:
    handler.doRollover()
print(Counter)
```
(That's my code) @chepner

Comment: ok Never mind it started working now for some reason